# Format a table column with superscript and operator

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation

I have two alternative forms of a simple table, both of which have problems:

```
table1 = 
  TableForm[
    Table[
      {CenterDot @@ Apply[Superscript, FactorInteger[x], {1}], MoebiusMu[x]}, 
      {x, 0, 10}], 
      TableHeadings -> 
        {{"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}, 
         {"prime factors", "μ[x]"}}]
```

and

```
table2 = 
  TableForm[
    Table[
      {Apply[Superscript, FactorInteger[x], {1}], MoebiusMu[x]}, 
      {x, 0, 10}], 
      TableHeadings -> 
        {{"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}, 
         {"prime factors", "μ[x]"}}]
```

`table1` fails to format the superscript properly - it writes `CenterDot[...]` (where `...` represents a properly formatted `Superscript`).

`table2` puts the `Superscript` prime factors on top of each other rather than in-line, and removes the lines that delimit the `TableHeadings`.

I want items in the first column to look something like $a^b.c^d$ and I also want the table to have lines delimiting the headings.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table2 = TableForm[Table[{Row[Apply[Superscript, FactorInteger[x], {1}], "·"], MoebiusMu[x]},
   {x, 0, 10}], 
  TableHeadings -> {{"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}, 
    {"prime factors", "μ[x]"}}]
```

[image]